# Java chat client GUI advice

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, chat

I'm looking for some guidance or just ideas here. We designed a basic/small Java chat client/server with a GUI. I'm thinking about developing this a bit further for fun.

I'm hitting a dead end with listing the users though. I would like a nice, clean list of your friends. With online/offline status and so on (even if its just a change in colour of the text). Maybe right click to whisper.

Anyone have any thoughts/ideas to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom JList cell renderer with appropriate JLabel and/or any other swing component. See example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help. I've implemented this now, but I'm stuck with one thing. Hope you can help me. How do I update one specific object/item in the JList? I've tried about 100 things, but think I'm not understanding the concept here.

Comment: Depends on how you have initialized the JList and how much data is contained within it. A simple strategy is to call jlist.getModel which returns a ListModel, iterate it, find your object and modify it. Since the actual reference is already contained in ListModel, you don't need to add/remove it at all. On second thought, you may need to call jlist.fireSelectionValueChanged method once you are done with the changes on objects contained in listmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I did this as my first Java project. My source code and executable are up for downloads.

Here [Source](http://www.plunder.com/source-download-ea26e9d6b4.htm) and [Jar Executable](http://www.plunder.com/Chat-download-de5c020c62.htm)